# simple_html_dom: simple use-case - to get back data for storing in SQLite db

Tags: php

i fairly new to simple_html_dom usage and methods. I know a little the parser,

**update:** since file_get_html is not a native PHP function, the function resides within my included file that cannot be found so i need to to fix that first. The filed does not exist by checking the inc folder in the project root.
i am going to fix it.

i want to gather some information from this site:

https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/organisations_en#open

is this possible to get the content - of let us say 10 or 20 last records on that page - and subesquently to store it in my mysql - db!?

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)

include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');

    //base url
    $base = 'https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/organisations_en#open';

    //home page HTML
    $html_base = file_get_html( $base );

    //get all category links
    foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $element->href );
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    $html_base->clear(); 
    unset($html_base);

?>
```

have the above code and I'm trying to get certain elements of the page but it isn't returning anything.

Is it possible that certain PHP functions might be disabled on the server to stop that?
The above code works perfectly on other sites.
Is there any workaround?

see some errors i get here:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(inc/simple_html_dom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening 'inc/simple_html_dom.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in [...][...]:11
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

and this one:

```
FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file on line number 1
```

**update:** since file_get_html is not a native PHP function, the function resides within my included file that cannot be found so i need to to fix that first. The filed does not exist by checking the inc folder in the project root.
i am going to fix it.

finally i have it like this:

```
C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\php\ ->here my_project-file_ 
C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\php\includes  (and here the "simplehtmldom-parser" from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ goes in
```

i am going to testrun now the whole thing on my machine - using ATOM

cf see the picture [image]

Comment: If you already receive an error on including files, then you have other problems than parsing a DOM. Check whether the included file exists. Additionally, don't use irrelevant tags on your question - it is not related to Linux nor Apache after all

Comment: hi there - nico - many thanks i will rework the whole thing.

Comment: i need more DOM insights - i need more knowledge on DOM

Comment: Sorry, but no: according to these error messages, you don't have any DOM problem

Comment: hi there good day dear Nico - i need to fix this in order to get preliminary insights into the issues

Comment: **update:** since file_get_html is not a native PHP function, the function resides within my included file that cannot be found so i need to to fix that first. The filed does not exist by checking the inc folder in the project root.
i am going to fix it.